# How to Change icon on list divider without refreshing the data underneath

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am making my list divider collapsible.Initially list will be expanded but user can collapse it by clicking on the up arrow icon and also icon should change to down arrow. I am unable to change the icon here.  Here is my code

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="selectHeader" id="bank_name" data-theme="d" data-divider- theme="d" data-filter="false" data-inset="false"  style="padding:0px;margin-top: 0px;margin-left: -5px">
   <li  data-role="list-divider" id="accountgrp">Account Groups

                 <div data-type="horizontal"  style="margin:-11px 30px -10px 0;display: inline;float: left;">
                  <a  id="grp-check-all" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="check-all" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext">Check All</a>
                </div>
                 <div data-type="horizontal"  style="margin:-11px 10px -10px 0;display: inline;float: right;">

                  <a  id="grp-clear-all" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="clear-all" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext">Clear</a></div>

                 <div data-type="horizontal"  class="openclose" >

                  <a  id="updown" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon='arrow-u' data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext">updown</a></div>


                  </li>

          <li  class="filterselect accountgrp ui-icon-arrow-u" data-icon="false"  id="group1"  ><a href="#"  data-panel="main" data-transition="slide"> Group1 </a></li>
            <li class="filterselect accountgrp ui-icon-arrow-u" data-icon="false"  id="group2"><a href="#"  data-panel="main" data-transition="slide">Group2</a></li>
            <li class="filterselect accountgrp ui-icon-arrow-u" data-icon="false" ><a href="#bankdetail1" data-panel="main" data-transition="flip">Group3</a></li>

             <li data-role="list-divider">Bank Code
                  <div data-type="horizontal"  style="margin:-11px 30px -10px 0;display: inline;float: left;">
                  <a  id="grp-check-all" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="check-all" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext">Check All</a>
                </div>
                 <div data-type="horizontal"  style="margin:-11px 30px -10px 0;display: inline;float: right;">

                  <a  id="grp-clear-all" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="clear-all" data-inline="true" data-iconpos="notext">Clear</a></div>

             </li>
             </ul>
```

CSS..

```
   .openclose{
       margin:-28px 25px -10px 0px;
       display: inline;float: right;    
     }
```

and jquery is here for first list divider only

```
$('#updown').live ("click", function (event)
{ 

var $span = $("ul.selectHeader").children(".accountgrp");

  if ($span.hasClass("ui-icon-arrow-u"))
{
    $(".accountgrp").hide();
    $span.removeClass ("ui-icon-arrow-u").addClass ("ui-icon-arrow-d");
    //$('#bank_name').listview('refresh');
}
else
{
    if ($span.hasClass ("ui-icon-arrow-d")) 
    {

        $(".accountgrp").show();
        $span.removeClass ("ui-icon-arrow-d").addClass ("ui-icon-arrow-u");
        //$('#bank_name').listview('refresh');


    }

}
    })
```

Comment: Could you post the whole HTML page? Thanks

Comment: @Tolis- HTML page have lots of tags. however i have updated it with the relevant code. pls let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to modify your code as following:

```
$('#updown').live ("click", function (event)
{ 
    var $span = $("ul.selectHeader").children(".accountgrp");
    if ($span.hasClass("ui-icon-arrow-u"))
    {
        $(".accountgrp").hide();
        $('.ui-icon-arrow-u').removeClass ("ui-icon-arrow-u").addClass ("ui-icon-arrow-d");
        //$('#bank_name').listview('refresh');
    }
    else
    {
        if ($span.hasClass ("ui-icon-arrow-d")) 
        {
            $(".accountgrp").show();
            $('.ui-icon-arrow-d').removeClass ("ui-icon-arrow-d").addClass ("ui-icon-arrow-u");
            //$('#bank_name').listview('refresh');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Since there's no explanation..., this works because you're selecting the `.ui-icon` element within the widget, and updating it like in my answer. **Be aware** that you are selecting all `.ui-icon` elements that use up/down arrow icons that are present in the DOM, so you could easily be selecting way more than you actually want (jQuery Mobile allows many pseudo-pages to exist in the same DOM at once). To fix this issue, change `$('.ui-icon-arrow-u')...` to `$span.find('.ui-icon-arrow-u')...` to select only the `.ui-icon` element within the desired widget(s).

Comment: Thanks Jasper for the explanation. I changed the code as per your suggestion. +1 for the valuable learning.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Mobile changes the HTML structure of widgets when they get initialized. Long-Story-Short, you need to select the `.ui-icon` element which is a descendant of the original widget in order to change the icon.

Long-Story-Long:

Here is an example un-initialized widget:

```
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f">
            <li data-role="list-divider">Overview</li>
            <li><a href="docs/about/intro.html">Intro to jQuery Mobile</a></li>
            <li><a href="docs/about/getting-started.html">Quick start guide</a></li>
            <li><a href="docs/about/features.html">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="docs/about/accessibility.html">Accessibility</a></li>
            <li><a href="docs/about/platforms.html">Supported platforms</a></li>
        </ul>
```

And here is that same widget initialized:

```
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="f" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
            <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-bar-f ui-corner-top">Overview</li>
            <li data-corners="false" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="div" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right" data-theme="c" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li">
                <div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">
                    <div class="ui-btn-text">
                        <a href="docs/about/intro.html" class="ui-link-inherit">Intro to jQuery Mobile</a>
                    </div>
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
                </div>
            </li>
            ...
        </ul>
```

Notice in the initialized HTML that icon classes are specified on the `.ui-icon` element.